# Get the date of the last day of the quarter preceding the quarter in which this date falls

Tags: date, raku

Given a date, return the date of the last day of the quarter preceding the quarter in which this date falls. for example

```
2020-04-25 => 2020-03-31
2020-06-25 => 2020-03-31
2020-09-25 => 2020-06-30
2020-10-25 => 2020-09-30
```

if the given date is in the first quarter, the year minus `1`

```
2020-03-25 => 2019-12-31
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sub MAIN(Date(Str) $date) {
    say $date.earlier(months => ($date.month - 1) % 3 + 1).last-date-in-month
}
```

This requires at least Rakudo 2020.05.

Comment: the method [last-date-in-month](https://docs.raku.org/routine/last-date-in-month) is cool.

Comment: @lizmat - please could you unpack the Date(Str) bit? Is it a call in a capture?

Comment: @psteve: it's a [coercion type](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-Coercion_type).  Basically, if the parameter is a `Str`, then `.Date` will be called on it.  Perhaps more known: `Int(Str)`, coerce to `Int` if it is a `Str`.  Or the shorter form `Int()`, which is short for `Int(Any)`: coerce to `Int` if it is an `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

```
sub MAIN(Str $day) {
    my Date $d       = Date.new($day);
    my Int  $year    = $d.year;
    my Int  $month   = $d.month;
    my Int  $quarter = ($month/3).ceiling; # the quarter that this date falls

    my @last-days = ('12-31', '03-31', '06-30', '09-30');

    # if the given date is in the first quarter, then `$year` minus 1
    $year-=1 if $quarter == 1; 

    say sprintf('%s-%s', $year, @last-days[$quarter-1]);
 }
```

save the above code as `quarter.raku`, the output is:

```sh
$ raku quarter.raku 2020-03-25
2019-12-31
 
$ raku quarter.p6 2020-04-25
2020-03-31
 
$ raku quarter.p6 2020-06-25
2020-03-31
 
$ raku quarter.p6 2020-07-25
2020-06-30

$ raku quarter.p6 2020-08-25
2020-06-30
 
$ raku quarter.p6 2020-09-25
2020-06-30
 
$ raku quarter.p6 2020-10-25
2020-09-30
```